# How to update Apache Tomcat Embed from 9.0.35 to 10.0.4 in Java application

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a Java application which shows Apache Tomcat Embed as 9.0.35 version. I need to update this to 10.0.4. I'm very new to Java and have very minimal knowledge on it. This upgrade is needed to resolve some vulnerabilities with in the application.

How can I do this from IntelliJ IDE?

Comment: Apart from the `javax.*` -> `jakarta.*` namespace migration, Tomcat 10 has very few changes from Tomcat 9 (cf. [Tomcat 10 changelog](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/changelog.html) and [Tomcat 9 changelog](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/changelog.html)): most changes are backported to Tomcat 9 and this includes **all** security vulnerabilities.

Comment: we don't know how your app has embedded tomcat, so we can't tell how to update it, either.

Answer (score 17):

## Tomcat 9 & 10 are equivalent products

[Apache Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) 9 and 10 are equivalent products. The only difference is support for changes for the package names in the Jakarta Servlet and related technologies from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*`.

This package name change is for legal reasons involved in the transfer of responsibility for [Jakarta EE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE) (formerly Java EE) technologies from [Oracle Corp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Corporation) to the [Eclipse Foundation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Foundation).

For more info, read [*Understanding Jakarta EE 9*](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2020/november/1.php).

To quote [the documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-10.cgi):

> Users of Tomcat 10 onwards should be aware that, as a result of the move from Java EE to Jakarta EE as part of the transfer of Java EE to the Eclipse Foundation, the primary package for all implemented APIs has changed from javax.* to jakarta.*. This will almost certainly require code changes to enable applications to migrate from Tomcat 9 and earlier to Tomcat 10 and later. A migration tool is under development to aid this process.

## Move to the latest 9 rather than 10

Tomcat 9 and 10 track the same development changes. If your goal is simply to gain some security fixes, as far as I know you'll get the same fixes in both 9 and 10. Do not take my word for this, just study the Tomcat Release Notes.

So for the fastest easiest migration path, just upgrade to the latest 9 instead of 10. The current latest version of 9 is 9.0.44.

## Stick with Tomcat 10

Alternatively, if you want to proceed with using Tomcat 10, change the `import` statements across your code base to use `jakarta.*` in place of `javax.*`.

IDEs such as IntelliJ have added features to assist in this migration chore.

And you’ll need to update any third-party libraries using `javax.*`  to new versions using `jakarta.*`.

Comment: I agree on the conclusion: Tomcat 7 was supported for 10 years. Since Tomcat 10 introduces a breaking change, Tomcat 9 will probably be supported well beyond 2030.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. We have a internal quality tool which scans different projects and then only it gets deployed Based on the scan recommendations we have to change or update he code. Then only it gets deployed. This is implemented across entire company. So there is no way I can bypass this. I have to update it to 10.0.4. So can you tell me how can it be done? Thanks.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I already did tell you: Change all occurrences of the `javax.*` package names referring to Tomcat’s Servlet/JSP/etc. technologies. Read the Tomcat documentation I linked. Explore their migration tool to see if that might help.