# Getting ClassNotFoundException for HttpServlet in Tomcat in INtellij

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, servlets, apple-m1

I am trying to deploy a Java web application to tomcat from Intellij. I am trying to test a servelt called **helloServlet**

This is my project structure:
[image]

This is a servlet class I have: **HelloServlet.java**

```
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private String message;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("Inside HelloServlet::init()");
        message = "Hello Earth!";
    }

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Inside HelloServlet::doGet()");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter responseWriter = response.getWriter();
        responseWriter.println("<html><body>");
        responseWriter.println("<h1>" + message +  ", this is get" + "</h1>");
        responseWriter.println("</body></html>");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Inside HelloServlet::doPost()");
        PrintWriter responseWriter = response.getWriter();
        responseWriter.println("<html><body>");
        responseWriter.println("<h1>" + message +  ", this is post" + "</h1>");
        responseWriter.println("</body></html>");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        System.out.println("Inside HelloServlet::destroy()");
    }

}
```

Below is my **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
        version="4.0"
        >

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>helloServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.ideawebworkspace.HelloServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>helloServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/helloServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Below is the **pom.xml** that I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>IdeaWebWorkspace</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>IdeaWebWorkspace</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.8.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

And this is my **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>New file</title>
</head>
<body>
    Welcome ABC
    <div>
        <form action="helloServlet" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" value="submitting">
        </form>

    </div>
</body>$
</html>
```

Now when I deploy it to tomcat from intellij, it gets deployed correctly
[image]

But when I click on the above button **submitting**(which makes the POST call to the servlet), I get the below 500 error:

[image]

[image]

Pasting the full error text below:

```
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class [com.example.ideawebworkspace.HelloServlet]
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:872)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1705)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Root Cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet
    java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2516)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:872)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1408)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1252)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:872)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1705)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1444)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1252)
    java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2516)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:872)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1408)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1252)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:872)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1705)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

From what I understood tomcat is unable to find the class/definition of the servlet api.

**My Analysis:**

1)I checked the process details of tomcat using the `ps -ef` command. And I got the below results:

```
501  5373  5102   0  7:44PM ??         0:02.94 /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/sagnikdas/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.3/tomcat/3eea1a67-841a-463f-a50d-176f09d1c1e6/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/Users/sagnikdas/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.3/tomcat/3eea1a67-841a-463f-a50d-176f09d1c1e6/jmxremote.password -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/Users/sagnikdas/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.3/tomcat/3eea1a67-841a-463f-a50d-176f09d1c1e6/jmxremote.access -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /opt/MyTomcat10/apache-tomcat-10.0.14/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/MyTomcat10/apache-tomcat-10.0.14/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/Users/sagnikdas/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.3/tomcat/3eea1a67-841a-463f-a50d-176f09d1c1e6 -Dcatalina.home=/opt/MyTomcat10/apache-tomcat-10.0.14 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/MyTomcat10/apache-tomcat-10.0.14/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
  501  5394  5294   0  7:47PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep java
```

What I notice here is that the tomcat process classpath has the jars `bootstrap.jar` and `tomcat-juli.jar` but not the `javax.servlet-api.jar`. Could it be a reason why I am getting this error.

**What I have tried**
1)Nothing seems to work, so I copied my `war file` from the target folder to the webapps folder of my tomcat installation(`catalina.home`) and then start the server manually using startup.sh. However even with the I am facing the same error.

My Tomcat version is 10.0.14

My java version is AWS Corretto 17

I am using `2020 M1 Macbook`, with OS monterey.

Could someone please help me with this.

Comment: What version of Tomcat are your deploying to?

Comment: @StephenC Tomcat version is apache-tomcat-10.0.14

Comment: OK ... so you need to read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66758269.  Tomcat 10 (and later) provide the `jakarta.servlet.*` etc APIs rather than `javax.servlet.*`.  Your webapp code needs to be changed, as do the dependencies.

Comment: @OlafKock yes the solution there answers my question. Thanks